# Convert Entity object to changeSet automatically

Tags: java, jpa, liquibase

I created many Entities Like this in my Java project:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="backup_item")
public class BackupItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public Path path;
}
```

Now I need to create the change logs for it:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="rrrr">
        <sql>
            CREATE TABLE backup_item(
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            );
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            DROP TABLE backupset;
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

Is there any tool that will create it for me automatically? I have at lease 10 tables and it will take me a lot of time to create them manually one by one.

Comment: You need `Hibernate Envers` or `Spring Data JPA Auditing`. Examples are here https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: Nope as long as I know liquibase does support some kind of code generator but it isn't sufficient enough like for an example .NET's SQL migrations, your going to have to write it by yourself if you want reliable script.

Comment: If you have a database created with those tables you can use liquibase to generate the changelogs for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use liquibase-maven-plugin as shown in chapter 6. (titled: Generate the changeLog With a Maven Plugin) of this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app

Although the auto generated changelogs are not that reliable and I even saw posts where liquibase developers don't recommended. They don't support a lot of stuff like detecting renamed columns etc.

It is recommended to write the changelogs manually as you have more control of the script itself...

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I use one of this 3 methods and it will create a DB tables automatically?

Comment: I updated the answer, from chapter 6: Generate the changeLog With a Maven Plugin onward